# Number of independent components of a unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

By definition, a $n$ dimensional unitary matrix $U$ satisfies the condition
$U^{\dagger}U=I$,
and
$UU^{\dagger}=I$.
I'd like to ask if these two equations are independent. If so, there will be $n^2$ independent equations of constrain, which is equal to the number of independent components of a general $n$ dimensional matrix. This is obviously impossible. If not, how to prove it?

Comment: Quite generally, for square matrices, $AB=I$ implies $BA=I$.

Comment: Both equations are necessary if $U$ is infinite dimensional. Consider a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis labelled by the natural numbers, and let $U$ be the shift operator that maps the $n$-th basis vector to the $n+1$-th; the adjoint of $U$ is noninvertible. Hence, $U^\dagger U=I$, but $UU^\dagger \neq I$.

Comment: That's not a physics question. (If it was phrased as one, it'd still be off-topic as homework-like)

Comment: Hint: An complex $n\times n$ matrix contains $2n^2$ real d.o.f.

Answer (score 10):

Let us assume that $U$ is an $n\times n$ unitary matrix, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
U^\dagger U=I~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
\end{equation}

The total number of entries in a unitary matrix is $n^2$ and the total number of *real* parameters is $2n^2$.

Let us further assume that $z_{pq}=a_{pq}+ib_{pq}$ where $a_{pq},~b_{pq}\in\mathbb{R}$.

From the equation (1), one can write

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n z_{ik}^\dagger z_{kj}&=&\delta_{ij}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n \bar z_{ki} z_{kj}&=&\delta_{ij}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
\end{eqnarray}

For $i=j$, the eq. (2) reduces to

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n |z_{ki}|^2=1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)
\end{equation}

Therefore, for $i=1,2,...,n$, eq.(3) represents $n$ independent real conditions.

For if $i\ne j$, $i \leftrightarrow j$, the eq. (2) remains the same. This gives $\binom{n}{2}$ independent equations, therefore, $2\times\binom{n}{2}$ real conditions:

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ki}a_{kj}+b_{ki}b_{kj})&=&0\\
\sum_{k=1}^n (a_{ki}b_{kj}+a_{kj}b_{ki})&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}

Total number of independent real conditions is $n+2\times\binom{n}{2}=n^2$.

Therefore, the total number of independent real parameters (components) $=$ Total number of real parameters $-$ total number of independent real conditions.

\begin{equation}
N=2n^2-n^2=n^2.
\end{equation}

Comment: I get that there are $n^2$ conditions. But it's not immediately obvious to me that the conditions are independent. Even worse, they aren't linear, which makes me worry about the existence of solutions. (Probably unwarranted, but anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

**Lemma.**
A unitary $n \times n$ matrix has $n^2$ real independent parameters.

**Proof.** An arbitrary complex $n\times n$ matrix $U$ has $2n^2$ real independent parameters.
The unitarity condition $U^\dagger = U^{-1}$ is equivalent with both $UU^\dagger = I$, and $U^\dagger U = I$ (using the definition of an inverse matrix).
So any one of these conditions contains all constraints on $U$. We pick the last one.
\begin{equation}
U^\dagger U = I
\end{equation}
Taking the complex conjugate of the product on the left hand side shows that $(U^\dagger U)$ is an Hermitian matrix.
\begin{equation}
(U^\dagger U)^\dagger = U^\dagger (U^\dagger)^\dagger = U^\dagger U
\end{equation}
This may seem obvious since $I$ is clearly Hermitian, but that is not the point.
Knowing that the combination $U^\dagger U$ is Hermitian,
we want to know how much $U^\dagger U$ has to be constrained to not be just *any* Hermitian matrix, but the particular Hermitian matrix $I$.

Before such constraints are imposed,
the product $U^\dagger U$ (with same matrix twice) has the same $2n^2$ parameter-space as $U$.
Every subsequent constraint imposed on the parameters of $U^\dagger U$ must then correspond to a constraint on the parameters of $U$.
The total number of independent parameter constraints to make an arbitrary Hermitian matrix $U^\dagger U$ into $I$
is simply all of its parameters.

From the condition for an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix (i.e. that $H^\dagger = H$) we find the number of free parameters. 
On the diagonal we require that the entries are purely real,
which sums to $n$ real parameters.
The conjugate symmetry condition on $H$ fixes all lower triangle elements in terms of the upper triangle (or vise versa).
The number of elements in the upper triangle is $n(n-1)/2$,
and each entry has $2$ real parameters.
Summing these terms gives us all independent parameters in a Hermitian matrix.
\begin{equation}
n + 2 \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = n^2
\end{equation}
So we remove $n^2$ parameters from $2n^2$
and we are done.
$\blacksquare$

**References.**
[Credit goes to Yan Gobeil whose proof I adapted to this.](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~yangob/groups.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can remember that follows: the $n^2$ complex relations $U^*U=I$ are not algebraically independent because both matrices $U^*U$ and $I$ are hermitian. If we consider the upper triangular parts of these matrices (included diagonals), then we obtain $n^2$ real equalities (write them for $n=2$). The previous equalities are algebraically independent; that implies that a unitary matrix depends on $n^2$ real parameters.

In the body of text, I change the notation $SU_n$ with the standard one $U_n$.

Let $U_n=\{U=[u_{i,j}]\in M_n(\mathbb{C})|UU^*=I_n\}$ (the other equality $U^*U=I_n$ is useless). $f:U\rightarrow UU^*-I$ is not an algebraic function in the $(u_{i,j})$; yet, it is an algebraic function in the $2n^2$ real variables $Re(u_{i,j}),Im(u_{i,j})$. Then $U_n$ is a real algebraic set defined by $f(U)=0$; note that $U_n$ is a group; then it suffices to study $U_n$ in a neighborhood of $I_n$. One has $Df_I:H\rightarrow H+H^*$; then the tangent space of $U_n$ in $I_n$ is $\{H|Df_i(H)=H+H^*=0\}$, that is the vector space $SH$ of skew-hermitian matrices. The number of real independent parameters defining $U_n$ is the dimension over $\mathbb{R}$ of $SH$, that is $2\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=n^2$.

Note that $f(U)=0$ is equivalent to $n^2$ real relations; that shows that $U_n$ depends at least on $2n^2-n^2=n^2$ parameters. That is above shows that theses $n^2$ relations are algebraically independent.

Comment: Thanks for the information.